# Display Taxonomy Image on single.php

Tags: post-thumbnails, taxonomy, single

I'm using [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/), and I can't figure out how to display a category's associated image on a single.php. Essentailly, when a user is viewing a post that utilizes the single.php template, it should display the post's category's image. Right now, it just doesn't display anything.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php 
    $image_id = apply_filters( "taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-id", 0 );
    if ( ! empty( $image_id )):
    print apply_filters( "taxonomy-images-queried-term-image", "",  array(
        "image_size" => "large"
    ) );
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Which part of this doesn't work? Do you get the proper `image_id`?

Comment: I'm not sure, no code shows up in the areas where the images should appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this little trick to obtain the taxonomy image given the ID of the term:

```
<?php
    $images = get_option('taxonomy_image_plugin');
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $images[$term_id] ); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how to use the filter proposed by the own plugin author
```$image_id = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-id', 0 );```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Lorenzo's answer, you still need to get `term_id`. This works, but seems less than ideal:

```
$images = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_plugin' );
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'byline' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $images[$term->term_id] ); 
    print $img_url;
}
```

The discussion [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/querying-for-image-of-term?replies=5) may be helpful.